# Convertir Milisegundos a MM:SS,000 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

se algo de programación de Java y MSSQL pero no tengo nidea de JavaScript.

Siguiendo un tutorial he conseguido lo que buscava, tratar un JSON para extaer información y mostrar-la en HTML, el problema que tengo y despues de buscar e intentar hacer diferentes cosas, no conigo que funcione, es, tengo un campo del JSON en MS y lo quiero mostrar en mm:ss,000

Segun lo que he construido, me podrias ayudar o orientar como tendria que hacer-lo?

JSON:

```
[
    {
      "BallastKG": 0,
      "BestLap": 278516,
      "CarId": 0,
      "CarModel": "av_citroen_ds3_r3t",
      "DriverName": "USER1",
      "Restrictor": 0,
      "TotalTime": 5377201,
      "HasPenalty": false,
      "PenaltyTime": 0,
      "LapPenalty": 0,
      "Disqualified": false,
      "ClassID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    },
    {
      "BallastKG": 0,
      "BestLap": 278859,
      "CarId": 1,
      "CarModel": "av_citroen_ds3_r3t",
      "DriverName": "USER2",
      "Restrictor": 0,
      "TotalTime": 3944203,
      "HasPenalty": false,
      "PenaltyTime": 0,
      "LapPenalty": 0,
      "Disqualified": false,
      "ClassID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
    ]
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Tiempos</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
        
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section">
                <button class="btn" id="week27">Week27</button>
                <button class="btn" id="week29">Week29</button>

                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Piloto</th>
                            <th>Coche</th>
                            <th>Tiempo</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="res">

                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>


        <script src="ajax1.js"></script>
    </body>


</html>
```

JS:

```
//console.log('correcto');

document.querySelector('#week29').addEventListener('click', traerDatos);
document.querySelector('#week27').addEventListener('click', traerDatos2);

function traerDatos() {
    //console.log('dentro de la funcion');

    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open('GET', 'WEEK29.json', true);

    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){

            //console.log(this.responseText);
            let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            //console.log(datos);

            let res = document.querySelector('#res');
            res.innerHTML = '';

            for(let item of datos){

                res.innerHTML += `
                    <tr>
                        <td>${item.DriverName}</td>
                        <td>${item.CarModel}</td>
                        <td>${item.BestLap}</td>
                    </tr>
                `

            }
        }

    }


}
function traerDatos2() {
    //console.log('dentro de la funcion');

    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open('GET', 'WEEK27.json', true);

    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){

            //console.log(this.responseText);
            let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            //console.log(datos);

            let res = document.querySelector('#res');
            res.innerHTML = '';

            for(let item of datos){

                res.innerHTML += `
                    <tr>
                        <td>${item.DriverName}</td>
                        <td>${item.CarModel}</td>
                        <td>${item.BestLap}</td>
                    </tr>
                `

            }
        }

    }


}
```

Tambien preguntar si hay alguna manera de optimizar el codigo JS, ya que podria tener +40 JSON y no tener que ir añadienndo codigo repetido y mil botones?

Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias aclarar cual es el campo que queres transformar? de paso, seguro (o casi seguro) que las funciones pueden recibir parametros... porque no pasas el nombre del json (que parece ser lo unico que cambia) por parametro?

Comment: Los minutos se obtienen dividiendo los milisegundos entre 60 mil y tomando la parte entera. La parte decimal la guardas para calcular los segundos y aplicas la misma operación anterior, pero esta vez sólo divides entre mil. Por último los decimales de la segunda división serán los milisegundos restantes. Matemáticas.

Comment: El campo que tengo que tratar es BestLap, revisare lo de pasar por paramtro el JSON, para ver si asi no tengo que duplicar el codigo.Gracias

@MauricioContreras eso lo revise, pero si intento hacer un tratamiento luego no se ponerlo en la tabla... no se donnde tratarlo ni como..

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Puedes crear una función que tome como entrada los milisegundos y la salida sea la cadena con el formato que deseas mostrar. Luego en la plantilla basta con poner `${tuFuncion(item.bestLap)}`, por ejemplo. Saludos